# Exact meaning of "sorted"

Tags: c, sorting

For a homework I have to write a fonction which returns if the array passed as a parameter is sorted:

```
int    ft_is_sorted(int *tab, int length, int (*f)(int, int))
{
    //My code
}
```

My question is: What does "sorted" mean?

My first instinct would be to say that both `[10, 8, 3, 1]` and `[1, 3, 8, 10]` are sorted. But when I checked http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/is_sorted/ I saw that here they consider the array sorted only if it is **ascending**.

I do not want to open any debate about the meaning of **sorted** in general, but if sorted has a special meaning in **programming**, please tell me so!

Comment: IMHO you should check two cases here

Comment: IMHO sorted array could be  numerical , alphabetical order . So it should be from lowest to highest.

Comment: No, sorted does not have any "special" meaning in programming. Generally arrays or lists ordered from the "smallest" to the "largest" element (whether numerical or alphabetical) are considered sorted, unless specified otherwise.

Comment: In computer science, arranging in an ordered sequence is called "sorting". Take a look [HERE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting)

Comment: You should have asked your teacher.

Comment: @Olaf I did but he found it funnier not to answer and smile at me.

Comment: Thanks to add comment if you downvote

Comment: Why would there be any doubt as to what "sorted" means when you're handed a comparison function? Just use it, that's where you get your order from!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**For the C language**

The function pointer passed to your function is intended to be used as a comparison function.

Usually, comparison function are designed so that for two indices `i` and `j` such that `i<j` we have the following: `f(tab[i], tab[j]) < 0` if `tab[i]` and `tab[j]` are in the *order* defined by the comparison function.

For instance `f` could be implemented as:

```
int f(int a, int b) { return b-a; }
```

to sort descendingly. And implemented as:

```
int f(int a, int b) { return a-b; }
```

to sort ascendingly.

*Reference*

- http://linux.die.net/man/3/qsort

**All languages**

There is no global convention among all programming languages as to how to define a comparison function.

- C++ uses a function returning a boolean, which defines a `a` is **less** than `b` relationship.
- Java use the same comparison prototype as C
- I don't know for other languages :)

Comment: We don't know about the semantics of the comparator function. Another common pattern is to return a boolean (with just two possible meanings: equal or ascending).

Comment: @NikolaiRuhe Except  I took the precaution to say: *usually* and that the **C** language uses that convention for 40 years. http://linux.die.net/man/3/qsort

Comment: I agree, but the OP explicitly referenced a C++ source, where the other type of comparators are more common.

Comment: @NikolaiRuhe the question is tagged **C** not **C++**, I believe he references the cpluplus.com website because he looked for a common "programming language" interpretation and assume the same conventions applied to all languages. I will edit my answer.

Comment: Hey, no offense. I'm not questioning the general correctness of your answer. I added this as a remark, since the OP does not seem to be too confident in this topic. Also, I added the comment before you added the paragraph with the precautionary limitation :)

Comment: @NikolaiRuhe no problem, that made me think about how to improve my answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Your homework most likely wants you to use that function as a verification to a sorting function that is to be written too.  "Sorted" in this context means "an acceptable output of the sorting function".

If you had to write a sorting function, you would most likely not write one that sorts either ascending or descending, at random. So match that.

We haven't seen your homework, but with what we've got here, assume ascending order unless otherwise noted.

Comment: The homework is about using pointers to functions, my function's signature is actually `int ft_is_sorted(int *tab, int length, int (*f)(int, int));` where f compares 2 numbers. So I cannot really assume I need to use ascending order just from that

Comment: If your homework is on function pointers, you can probably assume nobody cares about what's in the function as long as it typechecks.

Comment: I unfortunately cannot assume that ;)

Comment: @realUser404 Sorted is what the function `f` says it is. If it is assumed to be ascending, it is. If it is descending, it is as well.

Answer (score 3):

Every sequence can be considered "sorted" for some comparison function.

You need to figure out what kind of comparison function you need to apply.  Preferably in your implementation, you can leave it as a user-provided callback.

Answer (score 2):

If we assume that `f` is the comparisson function, then we assume that its return values indicate the relation between the two integers passed, implying whether they must be exchanged or not, generally as follows:

- `-1`: in the sort order, the first integer is before the second integer, so do not exchange;
- `0`: in the sort order, the two integers are considered equal, so do not exchange;
- `+1`: in the sort order, the second integer should be before the first integer, so exchange the values.

Loop repeatedly through the array until `f` only returns `-1` or `0`. Then the array is considered sorted according to the comparisson function. Note that we do not need to know what `f` actually does.

Note: in stead of `-1` and `+1`, the function could also return "smaller than 0" and "larger than zero", so to be safe only use that as a test.

Note: `f` could do anything, for example check whether the square of one integer is less then the root of the second integer. And you don't care.